# Android ExpandableListView expand/collapse only clicking on the indicator button

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a standard Android ExpandableListView on my Activity, where group/child view is a simple TextView. Regardless I click on the expand/collapse button, or on the TextView, it expands/collapses always. What I want, the list to expand/collapse only if user clicks on the indicator. How can I do this? For clicking on the TextView, different thing should happen.
Unfortunately OnGroupClickListener does not provide this info.
Thanks

Comment: You're better off implementing indicators as part of the group item layout.

Comment: @user3249477: so there is no standard solution for this then. Hmmm.

Comment: @Mike: please read my question again, no need for code...

Comment: I found a workaround: create an invisible view left to the textview (which is about the size of the indicator), and add an onclick listener, which will expand/collapse manually. So clicking on this looks like clicking on the indicator, and will do the expand/collapse work. The OnGroupClickListener is not called for this, but for the visible textview, where I can do different things when the user clicks on the text. It works, but I just thought, there is a simpler way to do this...